# how to build google gadget with persistent storage

Tags: google-gadget

I'm trying to make a google gadget that stores some data (say, statistics of users' actions) in a persistent way (i.e. statistics accumulates over time and over multiple users). Also I want these data to be placed at google free hosting, possibly together with the gadget itself.
Any ideas on how to do that?

I know, Google gadgets API has tools for working with remote data, but then the question is where to host it. Google Wave seemed to be an option, but it is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a server and host it there.

You have then the best control over the code, the performance and the data itself.

There are several hosting providers out there who provide hosting for a reasonable price.

Naming some: Hostgator.com (US), Hetzner.de (DE), http://swedendedicated.com (SE, never used, just a quick search on the internet).